# The use of "ln" in System.out.print("");?

Tags: java

I'm doing an intro course in Java and I just wanted to know, because my professor isn't very smart, what the difference between:

`System.out.print("Hello World!");`

and

`System.out.println("Hello World!");`

He said it's something about a new line but he doesn't explain very well so ... Thanks!

Comment: Please use google - this was the first result: http://www.coderanch.com/t/394386/java/java/system-print-println

Comment: You might underestimate your professor...  It prints out a newline, which means that the next print statement goes on the next line all the way to the left.

Comment: Please try to figure out these things for yourself before asking the SO community.

Comment: I believe professor is sure that it obvious for students to look at javadoc

Comment: This kind of feels like a troll, but in case it isn't: Please spend some time reading the [help], particularly [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you hover over the down arrow, the tool-tip says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". It may seem odd but Alex is correct in that Stack Overflow doesn't want questions that can already be answered very easily with a little searching. Too many poor questions can result in a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that:

`System.out.print("Hello World!");` prints just `Hello World!` to the console.

`System.out.println("Hello World!");` prints `Hello World!` as well as a new line! So your next output would start on a new line!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Test it for yourself as follows:

Case 1:

```
System.out.print("Hello");
System.out.print("World");
```

Case 2:

```
System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println("World");
```

if you cannot do it right now, here is the output:

Case 1:

> HelloWorld

Case 2:

> Hello
>   World

You can also [refer to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following snippets and their corresponding outputs:

Snippet 1:

```
System.out.println("hello");
System.out.println("world");
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

Snippet 2:

```
System.out.print("hello");
System.out.print("world);
```

Output:

```
helloworld
```

`println` prints an additional new line due to which "world" gets printed in a different line.

Answer (score 0):

`print` will not move cursor to new line

```
System.out.print("Hello World!");
System.out.print("Hello World!");
System.out.print("Hello World!");
```

Output:

> Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!

`println` will move cursor to the new line

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
System.out.println("Hello World!");
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

Output:

> "Hello World!"
>   "Hello World!"
>   "Hello World!"

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
System.out.print("Hello World!");
System.out.print("Hello World!");
```

The output will be:

> Hello World!Hello World!

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

The output will be:

> Hello World!
>   Hello World!